# Problema com filtros e rotas no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

Oi. Estou criando uma api no laravel.

E tenho um problema com as rotas e filtros para o acesso. Tenho os níveis de cliente, operador e administrador.

Tenho rotas que são comum para cliente, operador e administrador, tenho rotas para operador e administrador e tenho rotas exclusiva para administrador.

Tentei fazer os grupos assim:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
// Rotas em comum
Route::resource('type', 'TypeController');
Route::resource('state', 'StateController');
Route::resource('solicitation', 'SolicitationController');
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');

// Rotas do operador
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.operator'), function()
{
    Route::resource('location', 'LocationController');
    Route::resource('login_desktop', 'LoginDesktopController');
});

// Rotas do administrador
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.administrator'), function()
{
    Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');
    Route::resource('jobtitle', 'JobTitleController');
    Route::resource('location', 'LocationController');
    Route::resource('login_desktop', 'LoginDesktopController');
});});
```

E esses são os filtros:

```
Route::filter('auth.administrator', function(){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->permission !== 'administrator')
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar este serviço.'),
        403
    );
}});

Route::filter('auth.operator', function(){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->permission !== 'operator')
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar este serviço.'),
        403
    );
}});

Route::filter('auth.client', function(){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user->permission !== 'client')
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar este serviço.'),
        403
    );
}});
```

Mais quando entro como um conta com nível de administrador funciona normalmente a rota, mais quando tendo acessar como operador da erro na validação.

O erro que da é que ele entra no filtro do operador e depois ele entra no filtro do administrador.

Gostaria de saber se tem como validar só para operador sem entrar no filtro do administrador.

Comment: Já tive esse problema. Para cada `Route::group`, você vai ter que dar um if para verificar se o nível da rota do grupo é o mesmo que vem do Auth::user(). O problema é que parece que para Route::controller e Route::resource, o Laravel só aceita registrar uma validação uma única vez.

Comment: Ou você pode fazer uma implementação de um ACL no Laravel. (Eu fiz em dois sistemas que uso Laravel, e acho que fica muito bom!). Exemplo: http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/03/18/a-simplified-laravel-acl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta juntar rotas para o mesmo resource num novo filtro, por exemplo

```
Route::filter('auth.administrator_or_operator', function(){
   $groups = ["administrator", "operator"];

   if(!in_array($user->permission, $groups)){
       return Response::json(array(
         'error' => true,
         'message' => 'Você não tem permissão para acessar este serviço.'),
         403
       );
   }
});
```

Aí as rotas ficariam:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
// Rotas em comum
Route::resource('type', 'TypeController');
Route::resource('state', 'StateController');
Route::resource('solicitation', 'SolicitationController');
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');

// Rotas do operador
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.operator'), function()
{
    //não ficou nada aqui
});

// Rotas do administrador
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.administrator'), function()
{
    Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');
    Route::resource('jobtitle', 'JobTitleController');
});});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.administrator_or_operator'), function(){
    Route::resource('location', 'LocationController');
    Route::resource('login_desktop', 'LoginDesktopController');
});
```

Isso tudo por que as rotas tem o mesmo nome, outra solução seria dar nomes diferentes para elas: location-admin, location-operator ...

Comment: Você também pode usar os pacotes do zizaco, são mais completos para autenticação e níveis de usuário: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust e https://github.com/Zizaco/confide

Comment: Ou também usar o Sentry: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#laravel-4

Comment: Eu fiz desse jeito aqui, mais o único problema é que se eu for restringir o acesso o algumas rotas para o operator como a "location.delete", eu não vou poder fazer pelo arquivo de rotas. Mais isso não é um problema muito grande pois eu posso restringir no controller, mais eu vou estudar as outras duas soluções que você me passou.